# WP search in metadata post

Tags: search, meta-query, pre-get-posts

In want to search by meta data value in post but I didn't succes.
For example if I type "sound" I want to found "sounddiary" for example.

Here my code:

```
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {  
        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
        $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';
        $meta_query[] = array( 
            array(
                'key' => 'album-artist',
                'value' =>  $query->query_vars['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        );
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    };
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_query');
```

EDIT:

var_dump($meta_query);

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(21) "album-artist"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "diary"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump()` your query and post the output as an [edit] to the question. I want to see what the generated `meta_query` looks like.

Comment: There are some plugins that may help you search in meta data. You can use this one: [https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/)

Comment: The meta_query is undefined, you are right.